# Ruby on Rails liquid theme detect current page and either display banner or not

Tags: ruby, liquid

In the **"view" only**... I don't have access to the controller or anything else.

I'm trying to figure out how to detect the page and display a banner or not display the banner depending on the page.
Nothing is passed down. What's needed is **IF** you're on this page > display the banner. **ELSE** - You're on this page - do not display banner.

```
<div class="thebnr"><img src="{{ 'thebnr.png' | asset_url }}" alt="{{ the.name }}" itemprop="bnr"></div>
```

I've searched and search but only see things like currentpage?  ... not sure how to get this to work.

Comment: Show the code representing anything related to the page, not the banner html. Is any variable related to page passed down to the view? Name of a pagination gem if you're using one?

Comment: No all that exists is the code displayed above. Nothing is passed down.   So what's needed is IF you're on this page > display the banner.  ELSE - You're on this page -  do not display banner.

Comment: Nothing is passed down but you need that information in order to make decisions. You see the problem here? You need the page variable or you just can't solve this logical problem. Also: What framework are you using? Your code is not a valid ruby interpolation e.g. `<%= some_var %>`

Comment: this looks like handlebars

Comment: It's shopify and they use Ruby on Rails.

Comment: Nothing has to be passed down through the controller.  It can look at the URL and determine what page it is just like PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a helper method in your:

```
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb

module ApplicationHelper

  def page?(page, returnval = true)
    controller, action = page.split('#')
    return returnval if params[:controller] == controller and ( action.nil? or action. params[:action] == action)
    nil
  end

end
```

Then in your view, you can use it like this:

```
<% if page?('controller#action') %>
...
<% end %>
```

`returnval` is a neat argument which you can use for modifying the return value of the `page?` method if the action matches the one specified. Otherwise the method returns `nil` and `nil == false` so you can safely use it in an if.

An example of using the `returnval` argument is:

```
<li class="<%= page?('controller#action', 'active') %>">
```

Comment: Funny how people can't really read.  What did I say in my first post?  VIEW ONLY.

Comment: @Jad If you declare this helper you will be able to access that information from your view.

Comment: Dude leave it.  I told you what's needed and you decided to do it your own way.  It doesn't  work that way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution -

```
{% if page.url == "/pages/about" %}
   <div class="thebnr"><img src="{{ 'thebnr.png' | asset_url }}" alt="{{ the.name }}" itemprop="bnr"></div>
{% else %}
   other thing
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This should fail with: `undefined local variable or method 'page'` unless you have a page helper somewhere.

Comment: Itay Grudev it works fine I'm using it now.  It displays the banner where I want it to display.  You are thinking to deep man, leave it...

Comment: undefined local variable or method `page'